# How to solve Translate API : TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType?

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, google-translate

I am trying to import a json, an extract of a telegram channel, and then translate it.  When I translate it, I get the following error.  I initially thought the json may be too large, so I reduced it, but to no avail. ( I have made #comments to make the code as comprehensive as possible.)

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re
 
#Opening and loading the json 
f = open('result.json', encoding='utf8')
data = json.load(f)

#Retreive only the messages tag from json

msgs = data['messages']

dmain = pd.DataFrame(msgs)


pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

#Put data into dataframe

df2 = dmain.filter(items = ['id','from', 'date' ,'text', 'type', 'reply_to_message_id'])
df2 = df2.head(10)
#Translates data (message and sender) from Farsi to English

import googletrans
from googletrans import *
translator = googletrans.Translator()
df2['from'] = df2['from'].astype(str)
df2['from'] = df2['from'].apply(translator.translate,src='auto',dest='en').apply(getattr,args=('text',))

df2['text'] = df2['text'].astype(str)
df2['text'] = df2['text'].apply(translator.translate,src='auto',dest='en').apply(getattr,args=('text',))


# pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 1000)
df2.head(10)
```

Below is the error I get when I run the code.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_31688/502556507.py in <module>
      8 
      9 df2['text'] = df2['text'].astype(str)
---> 10 df2['text'] = df2['text'].apply(translator.translate,src='auto',dest='en').apply(getattr,args=('text',))
     11 
     12 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4355         dtype: float64
   4356         """
-> 4357         return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
   4358 
   4359     def _reduce(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply(self)
   1041             return self.apply_str()
   1042 
-> 1043         return self.apply_standard()
   1044 
   1045     def agg(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
   1096                 # List[Union[Callable[..., Any], str]]]]]"; expected
   1097                 # "Callable[[Any], Any]"
-> 1098                 mapped = lib.map_infer(
   1099                     values,
   1100                     f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in f(x)
    129 
    130             def f(x):
--> 131                 return func(x, *args, **kwargs)
    132 
    133         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
    217 
    218         data = json.loads(resp)
--> 219         parsed = json.loads(data[0][2])
    220         # not sure
    221         should_spacing = parsed[1][0][0][3]

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    337     else:
    338         if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):
--> 339             raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
    340                             f'not {s.__class__.__name__}')
    341         s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType
```

Comment: Sorry, i have tried a lot like using regex to delete spaces, and all other existing solutions.  I have gone through every other StackOverflow issue similar to this but none solve my issue.

Comment: So did you search through, or post on, the [official issues page](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues) for the `googletrans` project? That would've been the next step I'd have taken. Also, you made sure to test this in isolation without the dataframe being involved, right?

Comment: Yes, I did, before I posted this.
 I also tried using different dataframes.  What is confusing is that old extracts from Telegram seem to work, yet the new ones I extract do not.  People suggested the data may be too large so I cut it down to one row and it still did not work.